# XP Sp3 LanManWorkstation Service Starting Slow

Tags: svchost

I'm experiencing an issue on a Windows XP Sp3 workstation.

At startup the "Workstation" service (LanManWorkstation) takes Approx. 2 minutes to start.
During this time all other services behind it are blocked behind it.

(I was originally trying to figure out why my Wmi calls were failing for the first two minutes after startup, which led me this).

I've added dependencies to LanManWorkstation to allow some of the other critical services to start up in front of it so I don't have to wait until it is done to access them [Wmi for instance].

During the time before LanManWorkstation starts up Explorer is unavailable as well (sits at "Searching for items").

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be taking it so long to get up and running, or how to go about looking for what is causing it? (This workstation shares folders so the service is necessary; disabling it is not an option)

I've scanned the system for viruses/malware as well (malwarebytes)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Rootkits are hard if not impossible to detect while booted into the OS, download this software and make a boot CD or flash drive, boot from it and scan the drive, rule out malware first then we can make other suggestions.

http://connect.microsoft.com/systemsweeper